# Firemonkey + iOS: How to activate In-App Purchase?

Tags: ios, delphi, in-app-purchase, firemonkey

To enable In-App Purchases in Xcode we going to "Targets -> Capabilities" and switch this property on.

How to activate In-App Purchases for an Firemonkey iOS-App?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the easiest way is to use a third party library called [DPF iOS Native Components](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dpfdelphiios/). You can find a Demo for IAP in the Demos folder, and you can find more information in the forum.

Greetings